# How to parse such a json response (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]

Tags: javascript

I am doing a pre-request script with postman.
From the API I access the headers, with res.headers and I get

```
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
0: {…}
key: "Date"
value: "Fri, 30 Apr 2021 13:56:36 GMT"
```

[image]

How can I get the value from the date here? typeof(res.headers) returns its an object, but it looks to me like an array of objects. I tried different versions like res.headers[0], res.headers['Date'] and so on.

Comment: That output looks like its from the console and hasn't had all the data items expanded. As such, they're hidden and we can't see the names in order to suggest 'em.

Comment: I added a picture, I think it is already expanded

Comment: An array is an Object in javascript, use `Array.isArray()` to verify if the object is an array. The problem is there is no `Date` property on your nested object, but rather each object has `key` and `value` properties.

Comment: add the real SON, even if it is a part, not a picture https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Look in network tab > response, not in the console, if you want to see the received data properly. Also in the console you can right-click what's logged then `store as global variable`. The object ill be stored in a variable called `temp1`. Then, in the console, type `copy(temp1)` to copy the value to your clipboard. Then post it here (edit your question)

Comment: Yes, sorry for the messy post. I only had it in postman and tbh didn't know how to get the raw json from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to edit some information into your question about what your stack looks like (i.e., whether this is Express with some sort of middleware, or something else).

What you have is an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). If your intention is to extract data from the `value` key of an object with a `key` value of `Date`, you have to first somehow find this specific object in the array first, then extract its `value`:

```
const dateValue = res.headers.find(cv => cv.key === "Date").value;
```

Furthe reading: [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example snippet:

```
let outputData =  [
  {key : 'Date' , value: 'Fri, 30 Apr 2021 13:56:36 GMT'},
  {key : 'Test' , value: 'TestingValue'}
];

// filter out the object from the array containing key as Date.

let filteredData = outputData.filter((obj) => (obj.key == "Date"));

/* .filter returns a list of all the objects from the array matching the condition. So we fetch the first object from the filteredData array using index as filteredData[0] and fetch its value attribute */

console.log(filteredData[0].value); 

Output: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 13:56:36 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to iterate over the headers array every time you want to access a specific property you'll probably want to refactor it into a more accessible form. Here using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and mapping over the `res.headers` array to return a single object.

```js
const res = {
  headers: [
    {
      key: "Date",
      value: "Fri, 30 Apr 2021 13:56:36 GMT"
    },
    {
      key: "Server",
      value: "Apache"
    }
  ]
};

const headers = Object.assign({},
  ...res.headers.map(({ key, value }) => ({ [key]: value })));

// {
//   "Date": "Fri, 30 Apr 2021 13:56:36 GMT",
//   "Server": "Apache"
// }

console.log(headers.Date);
```